# actionbar clickable buttons MIA

Tags: android, android-layout

this is an example of actionbar with clickable buttons in it i tried applying it to other activity but i failed to his codes are very simple but i cant see how he made it this is the example im talking about http://www.brucephillips.name/blog/index.cfm/2011/12/28/Android-App-Development--Using-The-ActionBar-Widget anybody know how he did it?when i tried it the actionbar is missing in action.
this is his code in java

```
package name.brucephillips.actionbarexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ActionBarExampleActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MenuItem " + item.getTitle() + " selected.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
}
```

this is his mainmenu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@+id/open" android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" android:title="Open" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_open"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/save" android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" android:title="Save" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_save"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/close" android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" android:title="Close" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_close"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/history" android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" android:title="History" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_history"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/settings" android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" android:title="Settings" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"></item>


</menu>
```

and this is his main activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/textview"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:text="@string/introduction"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where did you fail at? What's the Logcat trace?

Comment: no output. logcat says ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a building property

Comment: I'm not sure. The only thing I would suggest is to see in styles.xml if you enabled actionbar, and see if you have those drawables in project resource.

Comment: he doesnt even have the styles.xml yes i do have the drawables.

Comment: What is your implementation by saying "tried applying it to other activity"? Do you mind posting some code? His code is just like the API guide on google's site so I'm not sure.

Comment: i copied his codes and try to put it on my own activity so his action bar would show in my activity apparently it didnt show up.used same code as his same thing with implementation.

Comment: I have no idea by just staring at a piece of working code. If you want a detailed explanation of his code, you can read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: i just want to know how he was able to show the actionbar.well maybe most of the people who saw it would want to know how.anyway thank you

Comment: see my answer may this will help you..

Answer (score 1):

Try this may be your device don't have proper density to show menus.

```
 android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
```

put this in activity tag inside your manifest.

**update:-**

complete code for menus put this code as it is....

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidMenusActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    // Initiating Menu XML file (menu.xml)
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.getItem(0);
        String itemTitle = item.getTitle().toString();
        Toast.makeText(this, "First menu item is: " + itemTitle, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {

        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.menu_bookmark:

            Toast.makeText(this, "Bookmark is Selected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_save:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Save is Selected", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_search:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Search is Selected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_share:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Share is Selected", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_delete:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Delete is Selected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;


        default:
            return false;
        }
    }    

}
```

//main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

//menu.xml it should be in menu folder inside res

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_bookmark"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="mark"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_save"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="Save"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Search"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_share"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Share"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_delete"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Delete"/>

</menu>
```

//manifest

put uiOption in activity like this

```
<activity
            android:name=".AndroidMenusActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
```

Comment: i dont have an output mate.

Comment: what i dont get is where did he put all the other elements of the actionbar please explain.

Comment: you've change the whole thing didnt you?il try it brb

Comment: Martin first run it then we ll discuss according to you. remember os version should be 4.03

Comment: wait im taking a long time to run it il be back on you when  i run it

Comment: i did what you told me to do did you have an output?what output?

Comment: check this out the profile part i put it in here ignore the location tracking part its wrong http://pastebin.com/9kvLFg5k